# Is there an AliExpress API that can submit dropship orders instead of using Oberlo?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, aliexpress

Currently I am using the Shopify app Oberlo with it's chrome extension to manually send over dropship orders one by one.

This works find but I have between 100 to 1000 orders daily during testing.

Can anybody recommend a way to automate this using either an API directly from AliExpress (which the affiliate API is all I have been able to find) or possibly a laravel wrapper integrated with Shopify that has the ability to post dropship orders automatically.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 11):

I've been looking for similar documentation on AliExpress and found the dropshipping subsection of their API:

> Get Product Info: https://developers.aliexpress.com/en/doc.htm?docId=35321&docType=2
>
> Place an Order: https://developers.aliexpress.com/en/doc.htm?docId=35446&docType=2
>
> Get Tracking info from a previous order: https://developers.aliexpress.com/en/doc.htm?docId=40656&docType=2
>
> Other less-common dropshipping APIs are available from the sidebar navigation of any of these.

It also appears that you have to register as a seller (even though you're just buying) to get access to these dropshipping API.

You'll have to build a shopify app that can receive your orders and turn around to place them on AliExpress. I haven't seen a tool that can place orders automatically without coding.